# Reason for "cc" clobber when reading CPSR in inline asm (linux kernel)

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel, arm, inline-assembly

I have noticed, that all of the inline asm macros that read CPSR (or modify just the F/I flags) in 'arch/arm/include/asm/irqflags.h' use `"memory", "cc"` clobbers.

E.g.:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/include/asm/irqflags.h?h=v6.0.2#n155

```c
#define IRQMASK_REG_NAME_R "cpsr"

static inline unsigned long arch_local_save_flags(void)
{
    unsigned long flags;
    asm volatile(
        "       mrs     %0, " IRQMASK_REG_NAME_R "      @ local_save_flags"
        : "=r" (flags) : : "memory", "cc");
    return flags;
}
```

I think the clobber prevents the compiler from moving any use of these macros in the surrounding code.
Can please somebody explain how this works in detail?
I (think I) understand the "memory" part but I am confused about the "cc" because reading CPSR IMHO doesn't change the condition code register (and changing F/I flags doesn't change real status flags too)?

Reason for my question is that I want to learn how to write such macros correctly.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a futile attempt to stop reordering with compiler-generated code that modifies flags?  (There are no well-defined semantics for `+` compiling to an `add`, let alone an `adds`.  And a compiler could always put the flag setting and usage on either side of the asm statement.)

Maybe I'm missing something about what other inline-asm hacks might happen in other functions used nearby, and there is something important about this.

The `"memory"` clobber will at least help control the position of the operation relative to memory access to non-local variables, by making the compiler assume that any globally-reachable memory has been read and/or modified.  This might or might not be overkill.

For *setting* CPSR, I think it would make a lot of sense to use a `"memory"` clobber to make sure it was ordered wrt. memory accesses if this might be enabling or disabling interrupts, or anything else that might affect memory accesses.